# Quixel exported textures not behaving like they should

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have the exported Quixel textures for the material "shiny brushed steel" but basically everything it does is make my materials follow the albedo only and they are dark, even with some fine HDRI images as environment light. I'd like someone with lighting/texturing skills to take a look at my scene and tell me what am I doing wrong. 
Of course, removing the albedo helped a bit, but then I lost imformation and the material didn't do what it was supposed to. 
[image]

**EDIT:** If I saw it well, the textures didn't upload along the file. I include the scene in a zip via google drive if that's fine by the answerer. 
[the scene .zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B33RFc9jZBV5N2ZpckVabF9hX3M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use Quixels material setup? They created a node group in which you only plug in your textures. Here's the link:
http://www.quixel.se/content/blender/QuixelShader.zip

Comment: I haven't yet, thanks for the tip. 
Once I downloaded it, I append and select the QuixelMat from material folder?

Comment: I'm asking because that way I described I can't load the material itself, only the nodes (node 001, node 002 etc) and that don't say much :/

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to just append the material from the downloaded .blend file.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't matter now, I adjusted those textures in Blender so they look appropriate :D